# Как работает этот код

Tags: java

**Всем привет**, изучаю java с книжги, такой вот код, программа **выводит 25 1**. Самостоятельно допереть у меня не получается, не понимаю как работает цикл, объясните как оно рабоатет.

```
package test214;
public class Mix4 {
    int counter = 0;        
    public static void main (String []args) {
    int count = 0;
    Mix4 [] m4a = new Mix4[20];
    int x = 0;
    while (x<20) {
        m4a[x]= new Mix4();
        m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1; 
        count = count +1; 
        count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x); 
        x=x+1;
    }
    System.out.println(count + " " +m4a[1].counter);
}

public int maybeNew(int index) {
    if(index<5) {
        Mix4 m4 = new Mix4();
        m4.counter= m4.counter+1;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0 ;
}
}
```

Сейчас опишу , то что я понимаю...
`Mix4 [] m4a = new Mix4[20];`
создаем массив размером 20 с именем m4a.
`while (x<20) {`
пока x<20, в массиве в элементе по индексу х создается новый Mix4 и присваеваем его значение.
`m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1;` для каждого элемента массива складываем// 0+1//1+1// 2+1 и так далее .
`count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);` вот , с этого момента я уже плыву, count присваивает значение `count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x)`. самое интересное что я не понимаю как этот метод работает maybeNew.
пока `index< 5` , как понять чему равно индекс, сколько раз будет выполнятся if
мы создаем ссылку экземпляра `m4 . Mix4 m4 = new Mix4();`
`m4.counter = m4.counter +1 ;` 0+1// 1+1// и так далее
`return 1;`
`return 0;`
И по поводу return, в моем предстовление метод return возвращает значение, сначало он возврщает значение 1, потом 0.
какой смысл возвращать 0,смысл тогда этого метода.
как видите плыву очень сильно..

Comment: Метод `maybeNew(int index)` работает просто - если `index < 5` возвращает `1`, иначе - возвращает `0`. Все остальные операции делаются над локальными переменными и не имеют значения за пределами функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод maybeNew(int index) работает просто - если index < 5 возвращает 1, иначе - возвращает 0. Все остальные операции делаются над локальными переменными и не имеют значения за пределами функции. Этот метод можно переписать так:

```
public int maybeNew(int index) {
    if(index<5)
        return 1;
    return 0 ;
}
```

А вообще код очень искусственный. Функция `maybeNew()` не использует в работе данных конкретных экземпляров класса, её можно сделать `static` и вызывать не от объекта, а от имени класса

```
count = count + Mix4.maybeNew(x);
```

В общем, если коротко:

- создается массив ссылок `m4a`
- цикл на 20 итераций. На каждой итерации:
- создается объект класса `Mix4` и назначается ссылке в массиве
- внутри созданного элемента увеличивается на единицу `counter`. Всё, больше операций с объектами нет
- увеличивается на единицу локальная в `main()` переменная `count`
- если итерация меньше 5, то локальная переменная `count` ещё раз увеличивается на единицу, возвращаемую функцией `maybeNew()`
- после цикла выводится на печать значение локальной переменной `count` и значение поля `counter` второго объекта из массива.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше объяснение. `System.out.println(count + " " +m4a[1].counter); `   ставим на печать значение поля `counter` второго обьекта, выводит 1. Если поставить вывод для любого другого объекта, то будет тот же вывод = 1. Не понимаю почему так.  `m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1;    m4a[0].counter = m4a[0].couner +1;`  Какое значение хранит  `m4a[0].counter `   ?  Я так понимаю что оно не складывается с 1, потому что для любого другого объекта вывод такой же.

Comment: Я целый день сидел над этой программой, все время считал, не сходилось, но теперь я допер.            
                //0 count = 0+1+1=2
  //1 count = 2+1+1=4
  //2 count = 4+1+1=6
  //3 count = 6+1+1=8
  //4 count = 8+1+1=10
  //5 count = 11
  //6 count = 12
  //7 count = 13
  //8 count = 14
  //9 count = 15
  //10 count = 16
  //11 count = 17
  //12 count = 18
  //13 count = 19
  //14 count = 20
  //15 count = 21
  //16 count = 22
  //17 count = 23
  //18 count = 24
  //19 count = 25   Спасибо большое!